# How to script user authority for multiple databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm creating a website which has access to 2 SQL Server 2014 databases.

I'm a bit of a noob - I've only ever granted access to a single database before and I use this script:

```
USE [master]
GO
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.syslogins WHERE name = N'MyUser')
    DROP LOGIN [MyUser];
GO
CREATE LOGIN [MyUser]
    WITH
        PASSWORD=N'******',
        DEFAULT_DATABASE=[MyDatabase],
        CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
GO
-- Drop & recreate db-user
USE [MyDatabase]
GO
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = N'MyUser')
    DROP USER [MyUser];
GO
CREATE USER [MyUser] FOR LOGIN [MyUser]
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'MyUser'
GO
```

However, when I run the script on the second database, I lose access to the first database. I have access to both if I create 2 different users.

So, a question - what do I need to do to this script so that I can retain acces over multiple databases?

Comment: Why not just create one user in the security part of SSMS and then give level access to those databases with User mappings Under the Security Properties? It's much easier...

Comment: Only because I didn't know how. Sorry I did say I was a relative noob when its comes to SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first chunk of code in your script drops the login from the server, if it's already present.  So if you're running the entire script two times, it will create the login, create the database user (and associate it to the login), then drop/re-create the login at the start of the second iteration.

If you need to add this login as a user within a second database, all you need to do is execute the second half of the script for any additional database.  (Although as alluded to in the comments, using SQL Server Management Studio to do this in the UI is much easier.)